# Substituir texto quando não o valor não for NULL

Tags: php

Quero fazer com que o título das páginas que estão escritos em HTML sejam substituídos somente quando eu inserir um título personalizado. Qual função em PHP realiza substituições quando o valor não está NULL? Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não basta um `if( $valor === null )`?

Comment: ou até `if (!$valor)`

Answer (score 4):

> Depende do que chama de nulo.

O comentário do bacco está correto, você simplesmente usa a comparação:

```
if($valor !== null){
   // Substitui porque não está nulo
}else{
   // Está nulo
}
```

Entretanto existe uma diferença entre o que é `nulo` e o que é `vazio`, você pode usar o `''` para identificar o vazio.

```
if($valor !== ''){
   // Substitui porque não está vazio
}else{
   // Está vazio
}
```

Em todos os casos, para identificar se o valor não é vazio e também não é nulo pode usar o comparadores não restritivos `!=` ao invés de `!==` (ou seja, pode usar `!= null` ou `!= ""`) ou pode optar por  usar a função `!empty()`.

```
if(!empty($valor)){
   // Substitui porque não está nulo, não está vazio e não está indefinido
}else{
   // Está "nulo"
}
```

[Você pode ver a tabela de comparação de nulo e também de vazio clicando aqui.](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: devidamente upado. vamos torcer pra ser essa mesmo a dúvida :)